# why is my Resume Training code for my CNN model is giving me this error?

Tags: keras, neural-network, runtime-error, conv-neural-network

I am trying to build a CNN that classifies cats and dogs images but when I try and run the code to resume training of my model an error is thrown up. Here is my code for resume training of the model:

```
from keras import Sequential
from keras_preprocessing.image import ImageDataGenerator
from keras.layers import *
from keras.callbacks import ModelCheckpoint
from keras.optimizers import *
from keras.models import *
import keras
import numpy as np
import os

img_size = 200 # number of pixels for width and height

#Random Seed
np.random.seed(17897)


training_path = os.getcwd() + "/cats and dogs images/train"
testing_path = os.getcwd() + "/cats and dogs images/test"

#Loads the Model
model = load_model('trained_model.h5')


#Scales the pixel values to between 0 to 1
datagen = ImageDataGenerator(rescale=1.0/255.0)

Batch_size = 10

#Prepares Training Data
training_dataset = datagen.flow_from_directory(directory = training_path,
                                               target_size=(img_size,img_size),
                                               classes = ["cat","dog"],
                                               class_mode = "categorical",
                                               batch_size = Batch_size)

#Prepares Testing Data
testing_dataset = datagen.flow_from_directory(directory = testing_path,
                                              target_size=(img_size,img_size),
                                              classes = ["cat","dog"],
                                              class_mode = "categorical",
                                              batch_size = Batch_size)

#Recompiles model
#model.compile(loss="binary_crossentropy", optimizer="adam", metrics=['accuracy'])


#Checkpoint
filepath = os.getcwd() + "/trained_model.h5"
checkpoint = ModelCheckpoint(filepath, monitor='loss', verbose=1, save_best_only=True, mode='min', save_freq=1)

#Fitting the model to the dataset (Training the Model)
model.fit(x = training_dataset, steps_per_epoch = 400, validation_data=testing_dataset, validation_steps=100, epochs = 10, callbacks=[checkpoint], verbose = 1)


# evaluate model on training dataset
_,acc = model.evaluate(training_dataset, steps=len(training_dataset), verbose=1)
print("Accuracy on training dataset:")
print('> %.3f' % float(acc * 100.0))


#evaluate model on testing dataset
_,acc = model.evaluate(testing_dataset, steps=len(testing_dataset), verbose=1)
print("Accuracy on testing dataset:")
print('> %.3f' % (acc * 100.0))
```

However when I run the code I get this error:

```
Found 4000 images belonging to 2 classes.
Found 1000 images belonging to 2 classes.
Epoch 1/10
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Jackson\Documents\Programming\Python Projects\Neural Network That Deteremines Cats and Dogs\Retraining Network.py", line 52, in <module>
    model.fit(x = training_dataset, steps_per_epoch = 400, validation_data=testing_dataset, validation_steps=100, epochs = 10, callbacks=[checkpoint], verbose = 1)
  File "C:\Users\Jackson\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\keras\engine\training.py", line 108, in _method_wrapper
    return method(self, *args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\Jackson\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\keras\engine\training.py", line 1098, in fit
    tmp_logs = train_function(iterator)
  File "C:\Users\Jackson\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\eager\def_function.py", line 780, in __call__
    result = self._call(*args, **kwds)
  File "C:\Users\Jackson\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\eager\def_function.py", line 846, in _call
    return self._concrete_stateful_fn._filtered_call(canon_args, canon_kwds)  # pylint: disable=protected-access
  File "C:\Users\Jackson\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\eager\function.py", line 1843, in _filtered_call
    return self._call_flat(
  File "C:\Users\Jackson\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\eager\function.py", line 1923, in _call_flat
    return self._build_call_outputs(self._inference_function.call(
  File "C:\Users\Jackson\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\eager\function.py", line 545, in call
    outputs = execute.execute(
  File "C:\Users\Jackson\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\eager\execute.py", line 59, in quick_execute
    tensors = pywrap_tfe.TFE_Py_Execute(ctx._handle, device_name, op_name,
tensorflow.python.framework.errors_impl.InvalidArgumentError:  Input to reshape is a tensor with 6400000 values, but the requested shape requires a multiple of 1000000
     [[node sequential/flatten/Reshape (defined at C:\Users\Jackson\Documents\Programming\Python Projects\Neural Network That Deteremines Cats and Dogs\Retraining Network.py:52) ]] [Op:__inference_train_function_674]

Function call stack:
train_function
```

What am I doing wrong as the code seems to be exactly the same as my training code that builds the model and trains it:

```
from keras import Sequential
from keras_preprocessing.image import ImageDataGenerator
from keras.layers import *
from keras.callbacks import ModelCheckpoint
from keras.optimizers import *
import keras
import numpy as np
import os

img_size = 250 # number of pixels for width and height

#Random Seed
np.random.seed(123456789)


training_path = os.getcwd() + "/cats and dogs images/train"
testing_path = os.getcwd() + "/cats and dogs images/test"

#Defines the Model
model = Sequential([
        Conv2D(filters=128, kernel_size=(3,3), activation="relu", padding="same", input_shape=(img_size,img_size,3)),
        MaxPool2D(pool_size=(2,2), strides=2),
        Conv2D(filters=64, kernel_size=(3,3), activation="relu", padding="same"),
        Flatten(),
        Dense(32, activation="relu"),
        Dense(2, activation="softmax")
])


#Scales the pixel values to between 0 to 1
datagen = ImageDataGenerator(rescale=1.0/255.0)

Batch_size = 10

#Prepares Training Data
training_dataset = datagen.flow_from_directory(directory = training_path,
                                               target_size=(img_size,img_size),
                                               classes = ["cat","dog"],
                                               class_mode = "categorical",
                                               batch_size = Batch_size)

#Prepares Testing Data
testing_dataset = datagen.flow_from_directory(directory = testing_path,
                                              target_size=(img_size,img_size),
                                              classes = ["cat","dog"],
                                              class_mode = "categorical",
                                              batch_size = Batch_size)


#Compiles the model
#model.compile(loss="categorical_crossentropy", optimizer="sgd", metrics=['accuracy'])
model.compile(loss="binary_crossentropy", optimizer="adam", metrics=['accuracy'])
#model.compile(loss="mse", optimizer="sgd", metrics=[keras.metrics.MeanSquaredError()])

#Checkpoint
filepath = os.getcwd() + "/trained_model.h5"
checkpoint = ModelCheckpoint(filepath, monitor='loss', verbose=1, save_best_only=True, mode='min', save_freq=1)

#Fitting the model to the dataset (Training the Model)
model.fit(x = training_dataset, steps_per_epoch = 400,
          validation_data=testing_dataset, validation_steps=100,
          epochs = 10, callbacks=[checkpoint], verbose = 1)


# evaluate model on training dataset
_,acc = model.evaluate_generator(training_dataset, steps=len(training_dataset), verbose=0)
print("Accuracy on training dataset:")
print('> %.3f' % (acc * 100.0))


#evaluate model on testing dataset
_,acc = model.evaluate_generator(testing_dataset, steps=len(testing_dataset), verbose=0)
print("Accuracy on testing dataset:")
print('> %.3f' % (acc * 100.0))
```

And this code runs perfectly without any errors so why doesn't the code above work?

Comment: Your `img_size` is different in the two scripts. Is it intentional?

Comment: @Lescurel thanks for pointing it out that, the fixed it